# ReactJS remove dynamic element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to remove dynamic element in my program, but i think, i have problem with 'this'.When i click in 'X', nothing happens, console doesn't show any error. Maybe someone more experienced will help me.

('items' is array in state)

Main file:

```
removeItemCity(i){
 let arr = this.state.items;
 arr.splice(i, 1);
 this.setState({items:arr})
}

renderItems(item,i){
return(<Tiles key = {'key_' + i} index = {i} delete = {() =>                                                                           
            {this.removeItemCity}}/>);  
}

render() {
        return(
        <div className = "BodyAppContainer">
            <div className = "grid" id="items">
                {this.state.items.map(this.renderItems) }
            </div>
         </div>
        );
     }
```

And my component "Tiles"

```
 import React from 'react';

    class Tiles extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    remove(){
        this.props.delete(this.props.index);
    }

render() {

    return (

     <div className = "col-4_sm-6_xs-12 item">
            <h2>City : {this.props.index}</h2>
            <button className="removeButton" onClick={() => this.remove} >X</button>
        </div>
  );

  }
}
export default Tiles;
```

Comment: Hi, could you fix your style and indentation by first writing the question in a text editor, then later copying and pasting here? That would help in reading the code. Other people are welcome to edit the question to improve the style, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your onClick prop for the X button is not doing anything:

```
onClick={() => this.remove}
```

When you click, it calls that arrow function. But that arrow function only has `this.remove`, which is the definition to a method. The first step in helping you out is you should call that method using parentheses:

```
onClick={() => this.remove()}
```

The same thing applies to your `renderItems()`, where you are also missing parentheses to enact a function call in the `delete` prop passed to `Tiles`:

```
delete={() => {this.removeItemCity}}
```

Comment: thanks, but now i get this error in console: _this2 is undefined

Comment: You have to be more specific about what `this` and where the error was. My guess is you did the same mistake for this part: `delete={() => {this.removeItemCity}}` (you are missing the parentheses for the function call)

Comment: @DawidMalec you have to be specific about what line of code is giving out the error. If you just say, it's saying `_this2 is undefined`, we won't be able to help you out. It seems like your code has many event handler functions which require you understand how you bind the keyword `this` to match the correct component. I would suggest you read more about binding in React, maybe this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: u have right, thanks for help and link. I will read article and will try to solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <button className="removeButton" onClick={this.remove} >X</button>
```